# Best Way to Read a File in Chunks of Characters in Java

Tags: java, file, io

Let's say I have a class `File` which contains a reference to a file:

```
public class Streamer {
    [...]
    File f = new File(path)
    [...]
}
```

What would be the easiest way to implement a method `readNextBlock()`? This method would return the first n characters of the file if executed once. If executed a second time, it would return the next n characters, and so on, until it reaches the end of the file. For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Streamer streamer = new Streamer();
        String block1 = streamer.readNextBlock() //Return first n characters
        String block2 = streamer.readNextBlock() //Return next n characters
        [...]
        String blockn = streamer.readNextBlock() //Returns NULL if end of file is reached
    }
}
```

I tried implementing the iterator interface but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: You may want to look at the way these methods are implemented in the Java library. It's open source. In general, there is no "best way" to solve anything - it depends on context, and you have provided very little. Also, it's not recommended to create a class with the same name as a common Java library class.

Comment: Wouldn't that already be similar to what classes like `BufferedReader` are doing?

Comment: @Thomas: not quite, the `read(byte[],int,int)` method *does* give some added benefit over the normal `Reader` interface, but it won't guarantee `n` characters being read in case the underlying reader would block. It seems to me OP would want the `read` method to block and wait for more data in that case.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Exactly, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to wrap another `Reader` with a simple class like this:

```
/**
 * Read fixed-sized chunks from an underlying {@link Reader}
 */
public class ChunkReader {
    private final int chunkSize;
    private Reader reader;

    public ChunkReader(Reader reader, int chunkSize) {
        if (chunkSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Chunk size must be > 0");
        }
        this.reader = reader;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    public String readChunk() throws IOException {
        if (reader == null) {
            return null;
        }
        char[] cbuf = new char[chunkSize];
        int off = 0;
        int read = 0;
        while (read < chunkSize) {
            int ret = reader.read(cbuf, off, chunkSize-off);
            if (ret == -1) {
                reader = null;
                if (read == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                break;
            }
            read += ret;
        }
        return new String(cbuf, 0, read);
    }
}
```

You *could* turn it into an `Iterator` fairly easily if you want, but there's one small caveat: we don't quite know if the next `readChunk` call will return `null` if the last one succeeded fully (i.e. read a full chunk), because the underlying `Reader` could immediately return `-1` on the first call. So we'll need to do some sneaky look-aheads for this:

```
public class ChunkIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    private final int chunkSize;
    private Reader reader;
    private String next;

    public ChunkIterator(Reader reader, int chunkSize) {
        if (chunkSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Chunk size must be > 0");
        }
        this.reader = reader;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    private String readChunk() throws IOException {
        // same as above
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next != null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (reader == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            next = readChunk();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // could also return false, depending on your requirements
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```